# RxJava subjects and error handling

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I am trying to achieve a behavior similar to that of an event bus. For my requirements, a `PublishSubject` seems suitable.

The subject emits items representing a result of some global operation, which might resolve successfully or fail in case of an exception. I can't use `onNext()` for success events and `onError()` with the `Throwable` in case of an error, since once `onError()` is invoked the subject terminates and any future subscribers will get no emissions apart from an `onError()` one.

Right now the way I see it I have to create a class representing the event, and optionally referencing a `Throwable` in case of an error. This however seems unwise, as one would have to handle errors inside `onNext()`.

How would you go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a generic class wrapping events is a way to go. Say we call it *ResponseOrError* class, it should basically contain two fields

```
private T data;
private Throwable error;
```

and two simple factory methods :

```
public static <T> ResponseOrError<T> fromError(Throwable throwable) {
    return new ResponseOrError<>(throwable);
}

public static <T> ResponseOrError<T> fromData(T data) {
    return new ResponseOrError<>(data);
}
```

to remove some boilerplate code you can provide Transformer to make Observable of ResponseOrError type.

```
public static <T> Observable.Transformer<T, ResponseOrError<T>> toResponseOrErrorObservable() {
    return new Observable.Transformer<T, ResponseOrError<T>>() {

        @Override
        public Observable<ResponseOrError<T>> call(final Observable<T> observable) {
            return observable
                    .map(new Func1<T, ResponseOrError<T>>() {
                        @Override
                        public ResponseOrError<T> call(final T t) {
                            return ResponseOrError.fromData(t);
                        }
                    })
                    .onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends ResponseOrError<T>>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Observable<? extends ResponseOrError<T>> call(final Throwable throwable) {
                            return Observable.just(ResponseOrError.<T>fromError(throwable));
                        }
                    });
        }
    };
}
```

then you can use it like that :

```
final Observable<ResponseOrError<ImportantData>> compose = mNetworkService
               .getImportantData()
               .compose(ResponseOrError.<ImportantData>toResponseOrErrorObservable());
```

and now you can easily map result depending on success or failure or even provide another *Transformer* returning mapped *Observable< T>* instead of *Observable< ResponseOrError< T>>*

Comment: I didn't know about `compose()` and `Transformer` before you posted this, but there's actually a built-in type for your `ResponseOrError` type, called `Notification`, thought it's worth to mention.

Comment: While this does not call onError, it will still call onComplete and any subscriptions to your subject will finish and no longer accept additional events. You may be better served by using this strategy and something like RxRelay. https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay